# MySQL access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when creating a new Phoenix project

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a new Phoenix project with MySQL as the database. These are the steps I did

```
$ mix phx.new hello --database mysql
$ cd hello
$ mix ecto.create
```

This is the error I am getting

```
19:58:16.576 [error] GenServer #PID<0.2485.0> terminating
** (MyXQL.Error) (1045) (ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:87: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: MyXQL.Connection
```

I have MariaDB installed and the user 'root' has a password. How do I enter this password while creating a new project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot enter the database password while creating a new project.

But you can edit your repo configuration in `config/dev.exs`, look for the line with the comment `# Configure your database`.

Comment: Now Phoenix can access MySQL, but since the database wasn't created, its throwing error Unknown database 'hello_dev'

Comment: @RohitPrasad, `$ mix ecto.create`